# How to pass client certs in LWC Fetch API call?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am making an API call from Salesforce LWC Fetch to an external site. But this site requires a client's certs to be passed from Salesforce Cert Management. Below is the code. Any Help is much appreciated.

```
fetch(this.ExternalService.Endpoint__c.replace('{0}', this.recordId),
            {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((jsonResponse) => {
                if (!jsonResponse || !jsonResponse.result) {
                    this.showCustomToast('Response Error', 'Empty response.', 'error');
                    return;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // this.loadSampleData();
                this.showCustomToast('Callout Error', JSON.stringify(error), 'error');
            })
```

is there a way to pass the client certs?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of invoking the HTTP request directly from an LWC component, simply invoke an apex class that in turn makes the [callout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts.htm).

Apex provides a way to easily add the certificate

```
Httprequest request = new HttpRequest();
Http http = new Http();

request.setMethod('POST');
request.setEndpoint(endPointURL);
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 // Header info with remote server user name and password
request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
 //Check the client certificate
 request.setClientCertificateName('<your cert name>');
```

> The client-side is going to be unsafe from a security standpoint as you are exposing the certificate to the client-side code.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the reply. Apex is last the option. As Fetch API provides easy and loads faster.Looking to see if this can be achieved.

Comment: client-side will be risky from a security standpoint. On server, your certificate is protected.

Comment: Apex is much better option, we can also use named credentials (add certificate in named credentials), then use it in HTTP callout from apex.